# StyledDocument or RTF document to PDF conversion

Tags: java, pdf, converters, rtf, styleddocument

how can I get a `StyledDocument` directly or over the `RTFEditorKit` to a PDF file?
Currently I have a RTF document and converted this file with `Aspose.Word` to PDF, but I don't want to spend so much money for this library. I want to have a solution without using any OpenOffice or Microsoft Office API's.

Comment: *"I want to have a solution without using any OpenOffice or Microsoft Office API's."*  Why not?  BTW - good call on mentioning the money factor of Aspose as being the reason you do not want to use it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson If I use an API like the Office ones, I used to have this program installed, which is not actually the case.

Comment: Huh..  I thought OpenOffice provided a pure Java API you could include with your app., but never checked into it closely.